Doubt about having a haircut
I got a haram haircut and can I repent and ask forgiveness will all of forgive me for having a haram haircut

Az-Zumar 39:53
قُلْ يٰعِبَادِيَ الَّذِيْنَ اَسْرَفُوْا عَلٰۤي اَنْفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوْا مِنْ رَّحْمَةِ اللّٰهِ ؕ اِنَّ اللّٰهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوْبَ جَمِيْعًا ؕ اِنَّهٗ هُوَ الْغَفُوْرُ الرَّحِيْمُ
English - Mohsin Khan/Taqi-ud-Din al-Hilali
Say: "O ‘Ibadi (My slaves) who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah: verily, Allah forgives all sins. Truly He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.
Never despair of the mercy of Allah.
